# How to use AngularJS directive in HTML input tag?

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="text" no-special-char class="form-control" name="name" 
placeholder="" required="required"  
value="" ng-model="Name" required no-spl-char-name />
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: `Is this the correct way` - yes

Comment: Yes...you can directly apply directive to your input field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct

I would also suggest you go through this doc completely

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Check [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-angularjs-directives--cms-22511) too

**Sample**

**JS**

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.directive('myCustomerFunction', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   ...
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
   <input type="text" my-customer-function>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , we have use directive as Attribute and there are four way to use directive.

1. Element
2. Attribute
3. Class
4. Comment

please check following codepen with input tag for only character input.

```
Example :   https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/oeaRNm
```

Example : [AngularJS Numbers Only Directive](https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/oeaRNm)

Fore more documentation please check to [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Hope this will help you!